# Is MVVM appropriate for a .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid app?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, mvvm

I am preparing to create my first .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid app. It is a relatively new technology so there aren't a ton of resources to look at, but of the ones I have found, they are all structured like so:
[image]

With standard .NET MAUI apps, most people use the MVVM design pattern from what I can tell. Those look like the following as an example:

[image]

Of all the .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid examples I have seen, NONE of them have the views, models, and view models broken up with the same file structure that I see with standard .NET MAUI apps. I don't see any reason why the standard .NET MAUI apps would have a different design pattern than the hybrid apps, but perhaps I am missing something. Is MVVM still appropriate for .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid or is there a different design pattern that is more common place that I'm unaware of? If MVVM is still the way to go, why are the file structures set up differently?

Comment: Maybe it's because Blazor itself doesn't use MVVM.  If you're building UI out of HTML, that would be the Blazor side, not the Maui side.